# access to elements in IBOutletCollection

Tags: swift, iboutletcollection

I have an `IBOutletCollection` of `UIImageView`
now I need to access to imges in it, how I can do it?
I just can access to the first and the list by this code

```
myCollection.first?.image
myCollection.last?.image
```

I need to access to other images

Comment: `myCollection[0].image`, `myCollection[1].image`, `myCollection[2].image`, try!

Comment: @Mr.UB it's work! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IBOutletCollection` is an Array, hence to access its element we can use subscripts, like we do to access elements from normal array.

So to access its elements:

```
myCollection[0].image //or myCollection.first?.image 
myCollection[1].image 
myCollection[2].image
....
myCollection.last?.image
```